# FIle Transfer broadcasting

Tags: networking, scp, broadcast

I am curious are there implementations where one can send a file over a broadcast address like in IPv4 addresses to multiple end hosts?

For instance can `scp` perform a file Broadcast to multiple hosts

```
scp myFile.txt host@192.168.50.255:/home/hostname
```

An obvious way to do instantaneous `scp` over two or more hosts is by using `&&` operator but what happens when the host numbers are more than 20+

Comment: I think what you are looking to do is technically a multicast, not broadcast.

Comment: Multicasting is definitely a good option here thanks @MariusMatutiae

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it can be done. Jakuje is right that it cannot be done in TCP, however his reply does not cover UDP, which is instead used exactly for this.

I used for some time [this Java program](https://ulrichbuschbaum.wordpress.com/2015/04/06/sending-an-object-via-udp-multicast-using-java/) to do this, but then I discovered that [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/) can do it,

> Multicast is supported in Clonezilla SE, which is suitable for massive clone

and this gave me the motivation to look into how they did it: the authors of Clonezilla themselves [state they use UDPCast](http://iwcse.phys.ntu.edu.tw/parallel/Oct15/Steven_Shiau_131015.pdf) for this, and this is all: [UDPCast's Web page](https://www.udpcast.linux.lu/) states

> UDPcast is a file transfer tool that can send data simultaneously to many destinations on a LAN. This can for instance be used to install entire classrooms of PC's at once. The advantage of UDPcast over using other methods (nfs, ftp, whatever) is that UDPcast uses UDP's multicast abilities: it won't take longer to install 15 machines than it would to install just 2.

It is in the repos for the distros I use (Debian, Kubuntu, Arch Linux), so I presume it will be in just about all repos.

Answer (score 0):

No. It does not work like this. `scp` works over `ssh` protocol, which is connection-based (TCP) and therefore it can not do broadcast. It sends data and receives confirmation that the data were received correctly by the other side.

You could do that with significant modification of the client, that would open connection to more servers and would send data over to all of them, but it is not a *real* broadcast.